# Block a live click event until that function isn't over?

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, live, animated

Can someone help me fix this code, please?
What I want is to block the live (`'click'`) function until the `sliddingright` function is done.

```
('li.menu-item').live('click', function(event){
    if( !$(this).is(':animated')) 
    {
    sliddingright(page_id_target_right,previous_right_old,previous_right,next_right,pages_numbers);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can `sliddingright` accept a callback?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by callback, but i guess it is possible

Comment: You would have to unbind the click event and then rebind it in the sliddingright() function.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to unbind the click event when activated and then rebind it at the end of my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a return statement to your slidingright function that returns 'standby' once the function has completed its task, save it and check its value next time 'click' is called.

Like so :

```
var state = 'standby';
('li.menu-item').live('click', function(event){
    if( !$(this).is(':animated') && state == 'standby' ) 
    {
        state = 'processing';
        state = sliddingright(page_id_target_right,previous_right_old,previous_right,next_right,pages_numbers);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but this isn't working in my case...

$(document).ready(function() {
var state = 'standby';
$('li.menu-item').live('click', function(event){
    if( !$(this).is(':animated') && state == 'standby' ) 
    {
        state = 'processing';
        state = sliddingright(page_id_target_right,previous_right_old,previous_right,next_right,pages_numbers);
    }
});

At the end of the sliddingright function I'm returning the "standby" state

Comment: The problem is that into my sliddingright function, I'm sending the state "standby" even if the animation aren't finish

Comment: I resolve the problem, I add :     
state = 'standby'; return state; On my last animated action in my sliddingright function

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
clickMe = function() {
$('li.menu-item').live('click', function(event) {
    $('li.menu-item').off('click');
    sliddingright(page_id_target_right, previous_right_old, previous_right, next_right, pages_numbers);
});
    $('li.menu-item').on("click", clickMe);
};​
```